# How to add background of first children of a div for od even

Tags: html, css

I have a simple section now I would like to add background color even or odd of a first child in a div

Here is my solution : jsfiddle[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pndsboe1/)

```css
.elementor-accordion-item:nth-child(even) {
  background: #CCC
}
```

```html
<div class="elementor-accordion">
  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title">
      1. Reumatoidalne zapalenie stawów – pielęgnacja i opieka nad pacjentem
    </div>
    <div class="content-info">
      Parkinsonizm (określany także jako zespół parkinsonowski) jest zespołem neurologicznym charakterystycznym
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title">
      2. Reumatoidalne zapalenie stawów – pielęgnacja i opieka nad pacjentem
    </div>
    <div class="content-info">
      Parkinsonizm (określany także jako zespół parkinsonowski) jest zespołem neurologicznym charakterystycznym
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title">
      3. Reumatoidalne zapalenie stawów – pielęgnacja i opieka nad pacjentem
    </div>
    <div class="content-info">
      Parkinsonizm (określany także jako zespół parkinsonowski) jest zespołem neurologicznym charakterystycznym
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected result something like this below

[no image link provided]

Unfortunately, my solution just adds styles to both children instead of the first one meaning the title.

What do I need to do to get the above result?

Comment: could you post link to your fiddle, not to the image?

Comment: elementor-accordion-item is column or row?

Comment: @krychaxp column brother it tough to style :(

Comment: @StepUp updated the link check it

Comment: @TheDeadMan sorry we had a simultanios edit. can you re-add the image link.

Comment: Also please be more specifc: `first child of a div` - you only have divs! What divs are you talking exactly about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, my solution just adds styles to both children instead **of the first one** meaning the title.

We can use the [`first-child`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) selector to get the title (first-child) after the `nth-child()`:

```css
.elementor-accordion-item:nth-child(even) :first-child {
  background: #CCC
}
```

```html
<div class="elementor-accordion">
  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title">
      1. Reumatoidalne zapalenie stawów – pielęgnacja i opieka nad pacjentem
    </div>
    <div class="content-info">
      Parkinsonizm (określany także jako zespół parkinsonowski) jest zespołem neurologicznym charakterystycznym
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title">
      2. Reumatoidalne zapalenie stawów – pielęgnacja i opieka nad pacjentem
    </div>
    <div class="content-info">
      Parkinsonizm (określany także jako zespół parkinsonowski) jest zespołem neurologicznym charakterystycznym
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
    <div class="elementor-tab-title">
      3. Reumatoidalne zapalenie stawów – pielęgnacja i opieka nad pacjentem
    </div>
    <div class="content-info">
      Parkinsonizm (określany także jako zespół parkinsonowski) jest zespołem neurologicznym charakterystycznym
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I am a little bit late at the party. Let's alternate `.elementor-tab-title`:

```css
.elementor-accordion-item:nth-child(even) .elementor-tab-title {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="elementor-accordion">
    <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
      <div class="elementor-tab-title">
        1. Reumatoidalne zapalenie stawów – pielęgnacja i opieka nad pacjentem
      </div>
      <div class="content-info">
        Parkinsonizm (określany także jako zespół parkinsonowski) jest zespołem neurologicznym charakterystycznym
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
      <div class="elementor-tab-title">
        2. Reumatoidalne zapalenie stawów – pielęgnacja i opieka nad pacjentem
      </div>
      <div class="content-info">
        Parkinsonizm (określany także jako zespół parkinsonowski) jest zespołem neurologicznym charakterystycznym
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
      <div class="elementor-tab-title">
        3. Reumatoidalne zapalenie stawów – pielęgnacja i opieka nad pacjentem
      </div>
      <div class="content-info">
        Parkinsonizm (określany także jako zespół parkinsonowski) jest zespołem neurologicznym charakterystycznym
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="elementor-accordion-item">
      <div class="elementor-tab-title">
        4. Reumatoidalne zapalenie stawów – pielęgnacja i opieka nad pacjentem
      </div>
      <div class="content-info">
        Parkinsonizm (określany także jako zespół parkinsonowski) jest zespołem neurologicznym charakterystycznym
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```